# procedure is not getting executed

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

trying to run below procedure, but temp table is not getting updated with TEMP_JOB_ID_FROM_JOB_DOC_' and date.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE scheduler_cleanup
(P_IN_DATE IN DATE)
IS
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'create table TEMP_ID_STAT_TIME_FRM_JOB_DOC as select JOB_ID, last_update_time_utc, status from J_DOC where 
LAST_UPDATE_TIME_UTC <= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 90 and status=''Sent''';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DELETE hub_sign 
                        WHERE job_id IN ( SELECT JOB_ID
                                            FROM TEMP_ID_STAT_TIME_FRM_JOB_DOC )';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DELETE j_doc 
                        WHERE job_id IN ( SELECT JOB_ID
                                            FROM TEMP_ID_STAT_TIME_FRM_JOB_DOC )';

    --EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'RENAME TABLE TEMP_ID_STAT_TIME_FRM_JOB_DOC TO TEMP_JOB_ID_FROM_JOB_DOC_1119';
    --BEGIN
       -- EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE TEMP_JOB_ID_FROM_JOB_DOC_1119';
    --EXCEPTION
        --WHEN OTHER THEN
          --  NULL;
   -- END;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE TEMP_ID_STAT_TIME_FRM_JOB_DOC RENAME TO   || TO_CHAR(P_IN_DATE, 'MMYY');
END;
```

Comment: passing date parameter as 30-11-2020 in procedure.

Answer (score 0):

That's the last `ALTER`; you're renaming a table to `TO_CHAR(30-11-2020, 'MMYY')` which - when executed - does this:

```
SQL> alter table temp rename to to_char(sysdate, 'mmy');
alter table temp rename to to_char(sysdate, 'mmy')
                                  *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-14047: ALTER TABLE|INDEX RENAME may not be combined with other operations
```

Should have been just `RENAME`, not `ALTER`:

```
SQL> begin
  2    execute immediate 'rename temp to temp_' || to_char(sysdate, 'mmy');
  3  end;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * From tab where tname like 'TEMP%';

TNAME                          TABTYPE  CLUSTERID
------------------------------ ------- ----------
TEMP_120                       TABLE

SQL>
```

---

Though, do you *really really* want to do it this way? In Oracle, we usually don't create tables dynamically. Renaming them so that they contain *date component* scales as a goat which flies (i.e. doesn't scale at all). How will you write queries against bunch of tables whose name differs by the "date" suffix? Dynamic SQL again? Well, good luck with that.

Two other options I can think of:

- an "ordinary" table with a date column; filter rows by including that column into the `WHERE` clause (don't forget to index the column)
- partitioning

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Littlefoot also, You can achieve the desired behavior with minimal dynamic queries.

If you really want to store the intermediate data then you can use the `GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE` or `PL/SQL collections`.

I am giving an example of how you can use the global temporary table as follows:

Create the Global temporary table:

```
-- use the data type of the column as per requirement
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE GT_TABLE (
    JOB_ID                 NUMBER,
    LAST_UPDATE_TIME_UTC   TIMESTAMP,
    STATUS                 VARCHAR2(100)
) ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;
```

Use the global temporary table in the procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SCHEDULER_CLEANUP (
    P_IN_DATE IN DATE
) IS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO GT_TABLE
        SELECT JOB_ID,
               LAST_UPDATE_TIME_UTC,
               STATUS
          FROM J_DOC
         WHERE LAST_UPDATE_TIME_UTC <= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 90
           AND STATUS = 'Sent';

    DELETE FROM HUB_SIGN
     WHERE JOB_ID IN (
        SELECT JOB_ID
          FROM GT_TABLE
    );

    DELETE FROM J_DOC
     WHERE JOB_ID IN (
        SELECT JOB_ID
          FROM GT_TABLE
    );

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'create table TEMP_JOB_ID_FROM_JOB_DOC_' || TO_CHAR(P_IN_DATE,'MMYY')
                      || ' as  select JOB_ID, last_update_time_utc, status from GT_TABLE ';
END;
/
```